# Swift : Core Data join entity

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I know that NSFetchedResultsController does not support multiple entity. But I would like to know what is the efficient way to solve the problem below.

Let's say I have two entity: catalogue and selectedProduct. I am fetching all the entity catalogue to the user so he can select some products the task is: only propose the products in the catalogue that are not in selectedproduct.

In SQL it will be like `select * from catalogue where productName not in (select productName from selectedProduct)`.

[image: Core Data model]

Comment: Do you want to use the FRC’s change tracking (ie delegate methods)?  Bear in mind that the FRC will observe only changes to the catalogue objects, not changes to selectedProducts.  Have you considered instead just adding a selected attribute to the catalogue entity?

Comment: @pbasdf I can't add a selected attribute cz in my datamodel each product can be in more than one list. so in the catalogue entity there is the list of products and each produced can be in in more than one selected list

Comment: Ok - can you show the data model, I’m struggling to picture it.

Comment: @pbasdf so the pb is between TblLesCourses and TblProduits( sorry I am french ) I want  when proposing the TblProduit to choose products only propose products that they are not already in TblLesCourses for the same listdescourses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In think the following predicate should filter the products as you require:

```
fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SUBQUERY(lescourses, $lc, $lc.listedescourses == %@).@count == 0",listdescourses)
```

I've used SUBQUERY.  In theory it could be done with `NONE` or `NOT ANY`, but I sometimes find CD doesn't parse them correctly.  Note that, as per comments, the FRC will observe only the changes to `TblProduits`, to if you were to modify an existing `TblLesCourses` object to establish a relationship to `listdescourses`, the FRC will not (unless you redo the `performFetch`) recognise that the related `TblProduits` objects should no longer be included.